# What does an `output is not a tty` error mean?

Tags: windows, php, git-bash

I tried to write the output of the command `php -i` to the a file using `php -i > info` and received the following error:

`output is not a tty`

What does it mean?

I'm using `git bash` on Windows.

Comment: Hmm.. In the directory you are running the command, is there a file or directory called "info" already ?

Comment: no, but after running the command it is created, only empty and the error is outputted

Comment: Please try an "strace php -i > info" then post the output here..

Comment: Which version of php are you using? Did the command create the info file correctly?

Comment: @gerhardd., it created the info file with lots of content inside. No output to terminal. What output do you need?

Comment: I'm using php  7.0.0, the command created empty info file

Comment: I don't have the time right now to write up an answer for this, but if any answerer wants to take the likes of https://code.google.com/p/mintty/issues/detail?id=56, http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/capture-console-win32.html, https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/399, https://github.com/rprichard/winpty, and https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/231 in hand and run with them, please feel free.

Answer (score 68):

I found an similar topic like this.
One Solution which worked for me:

Write

```
php.exe -i > info
```

instead of

```
php -i > info
```

So yust append the `.exe` extension to your commands and it works.

Found this solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44727575/2377961

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying to figure out for a while now why this appeared to sometimes work and sometimes not, and that was the difference!

Comment: the problem you're encountering is that `php` is a aliased to `winpty php` by default when running `mintty`. `php.exe` is not aliased, so it won't be launched using `winpty`. The aliases are setup by default because of compatibility issues, you may encounter those instead when not running `winpty`.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me with `node` as well, so:

`$ node.exe programname.js > output.file`

Comment: Unbelievable, but this really works, thanks

Comment: @CervEd excellent suggestion, this also worked for me when getting this error pipeing the output of curl to a node script. converted my command to `curl.exe {url} | node.exe {script}` and it worked great.

Answer (score 32):

If you happen to be using winpty under the hood, you have to pass the `-Xallow-non-tty` argument to fix this:

```
$ winpty python -c 'print("hello")' | grep h
stdout is not a tty

$ winpty -Xallow-non-tty python -c 'print("hello")' | grep h
hello
```

However, if the output is mangled, the `-Xplain` argument will also be required:

```
$ winpty -Xallow-non-tty python -c 'print("hello")' | xxd
00000000: 1b5b 306d 1b5b 304b 6865 6c6c 6f1b 5b30  .[0m.[0Khello.[0
00000010: 4b1b 5b3f 3235 6c0d 0a1b 5b30 4b1b 5b3f  K.[?25l...[0K.[?
00000020: 3235 68                                  25h

$ winpty -Xallow-non-tty -Xplain python -c 'print("hello")' | xxd
00000000: 6865 6c6c 6f0d 0a                        hello..
```

Comment: Solved the issue for me when using `node` through `conemu`.

Comment: Thank you so much...This worked for me.

Comment: This one should be accepted as the correct solution

Comment: it's a `winpty` error, `git-bash` sets up aliases for `node ipython php php5 psql python2.7`  to use `winpty` in the script `/etc/profile.d/aliases.sh`

Comment: just logged in to upvote this. With default docker desktop install and git for windows, I can now run docker exec -it from a script with the docker command defined as : DOCKER_COMMAND='winpty -Xallow-non-tty -Xplain docker' Thanks a lot! Note that the options are not needed on the command line in a shell, but apparently inside a script it does.

Answer (score 24):

What worked for me, based on Peh's comments to  stackoverflow.com/questions/33622087

> If you use C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe instead of C:\Program
>   Files\Git\git-bash.exe then the command works fine

Comment: This didn't work for me. I get the same error.

Comment: But it worked for me today! I don't know why it didn't work a few months ago. +1

Comment: just type bash inside git bash

Answer (score 3):

I believe this issue is more about how Git Bash handles piping, and less about PHP, because I encountered the same symptom using Python on Windows. The [currently most-voted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1158954/598796) does not work for me. It might work a few months later, based on [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1011597/output-is-not-a-tty-error#comment1688611_1158954) and a [follow-up comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1011597/output-is-not-a-tty-error#comment1737176_1158954). But I'm impatient so I choose to use the native Windows Command Prompt and, voila, it works!

DOESN'T WORK in Git Bash

```
rayluo@DESKTOP-10B0N4G MINGW64 ~
$ python -c "print('hello world')" > test.txt
stdout is not a tty
```

WORKS in Command Prompt

```
(env27) C:\Users\rayluo>python -c "print('hello world')" > test.txt
(env27) C:\Users\rayluo>type test.txt
hello world
```

Answer (score 1):

You are redirecting you output from your terminal (tty) to a file.
Therefore your output is no longer a tty.

The message makes perfect sense. However this should not be an error.

I cannot reproduce this behavior on a linux system.

Comment: Sorry, i did comment on the wrong place. please run "strace php -i" and paste the output (last few lines at first).